# What does the AdaBoost algorithm iterate over?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, adaboost

I am trying to implement the AdaBoost algorithm with decision stumps as the weak learners, although I cannot fully understand the structure of this algorithm. 
I am learning about the algorithm from the Wikipedia page - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost
Since the algorithm is iterative, we iterate from 't in 1...T' however what exactly is this T? is it the total number of samples in the data-set, or is this the number of possible features to split the decision stump on? If this is the number of samples, then would this mean that we could potentially split on the same feature in multiple weak learners? Or does the method of weighting the data samples stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

AdaBoost (and all boosting algorithms) train iteratively a number of weak models (specified as a parameter), whose output is aggregated to form the final ensemble.

So `T` here is the number of weak learners to train.

Comment: So how do we decide the size of T initially?

Comment: It's a hyperparameter you need to tune (e.g. using cross-validation). It depends on the size and characteristics of your data, but values like 50 or 100 should be ok as a start.